# Campaign Influence related

Tags: community, lightning-community, partner-communities

By following Salesforce documentation, related to Campaign Management Implementation Guide; Campaign is in use and is working as expected and as designed. All this is TRUE if the Marking users &/or Sales users are associated with User License = Salesforce.
My requirement is to enable the same functionality, for Partner user/Channel Partner/Experience user where User License = Partner Community.
Whenever, I'm trying to assign "Campaign Influence" permission set to Partner user then error is
"Can't assign permission set Campaign Influence to user . The user license doesn't allow the permission: Campaign Influence"
*NOTE: this time I'm using tags as this issue is related to Communities/Channel Partner*
Suggest please!

Comment: You set the License field = "none" on the permission set, correct?